# Check if each element of 1-D numpy array is in corresponding row of 2-D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays:

```
X = np.array([[3, 4, 1], [2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 1]]) 
v = np.array([1, 5, 3])
```

I want to check if v is in X element-wise, i.e., 1 is in [3, 4, 1], 5 is in [2, 3, 4], and 3 is in [3, 5, 1] and return 1 and 0. So, in this case my answer should be [1,0,1].

Thanks

Comment: You could test for equality and call `any`, e.g. `(v[:,None] == X).any(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Create new axis for v:

```
>>> np.any(X - v[:, np.newaxis] == 0, axis=1) * 1
array([1, 0, 1])
```

> **numpy.newaxis**: The newaxis object can be used in all slicing operations to create an axis of length one. newaxis is an alias for ‘None’, and ‘None’ can be used in place of this with the same result.

**Performance**

```
X = np.random.randint(100, 1000, (100000, 1000))
v = np.random.randint(100, 1000, 100000)

%timeit np.any(X - v[:, np.newaxis] == 0, axis=1) * 1
880 ms ± 110 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.  Just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about NumPy to use `array` objects, but I've made a function that will work with normal lists:

```
def check_correspondence(lists, numbers):
    for i in range(len(lists)):
        yield int(numbers[i] in lists[i])
```

Whenever you call `check_correspondence`, you need to convert it into a list or tuple since it is a generator. Anyway, it can be modified to accept `numpy.array`.